# What is the best way to store data for iOS app that allows easy data administration

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, sqlite

I wonder, what is the best way to store data for an iOS app that allows easy data administration. I mean, manage the data displayed by the iOS app (mainly "fill" it with initial built-in data, namely images and corresponding descriptions) from another utility app, but running on OSX)
Is it good idea to use Sqlite? Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You can use Firebase which is an online database owned by Google is very easy to integrate your app

Go [here](https://firebase.google.com/) for Firebase

Firebase also has loads of documentation for swift and objective c on how to install and use.

Hope I helped, Toby.